# Apenas o Password Hash já é o suficiente para filtrar a entrada dos dados de um campo senha em um cadastro?

Tags: php, password

Atualmente faço da seguinte forma:

```
$senha = strip_tags(trim($_POST['Senha']));

$senha_segura = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Gostaria de saber se essa é a melhor forma de proteger o campo senha e se utilizando o password hash é necessário utilizar o strip_tags também, já que o password hash criptografa os dados que estão entrando e gera um valor diferente no banco de dados, ou o password hash já protege o banco de injeção sql e outros ataques por alterar as tags e caracteres por um valor diferente?

OBS: eu também utilizo o bindvalue do PDO:

```
$query->bindValue(':senha', $senha_segura, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: strip_tags é um erro, pode prejudicar uma senha válida

Comment: O certo seria utilizar apenas o Password Hash mesmo?

Comment: Sim, o password_hash é o que você precisa (e o password_verify para verificar). Postei 5 links interessantes no topo da sua pergunta, mas caso ainda restem duvidas, pergunte aqui nos comments ou clique em [edit] deixando mais específica a dúvida não resolvida.

Comment: Complementarmente, o que você precisa conhecer além da parte da senha, está neste post e similares (uma pesquisa por "injection" no topo do site ajuda):  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70

Comment: O Bind gera uma proteção adicional (via código) em PDO, e em mysqli_ é proteção nativa contra injeção (bind nem foi feito pra isso, mas a proteção é um efeito colateral), ambas ajudam, mas preste muita atenção se houver partes com concatenação.

Comment: Qq coisa deixe um comment aqui que tem um pessoal legal no site que tem uma boa experiência nisso. E se os links acima não forem suficientes para satisfazer a dúvida, comente aqui que a gente analisa e tenta deixar a pergunta mais específica.

Comment: Valeu Bacco, eu vou tirar o strip_tags, mas em relação a prejudicar a senha válida, eu utilizo ele no cadastro e no login então mesmo que retire algum caractere na hora cadastro, vai acontecer o mesmo no login e vai validar da mesma forma, se for isso que você quis dizer.

Comment: Pense comigo: eu ponho a senha `a<b>c#d` --- No DB vai ficar só `ac#d`; eu como usuário nem vou perceber que minha senha foi corrompida, mas além de vc ter enfraquecido ela, vai gerar problemas em certas partes e outras não. O usuário não tem sequer como analisar o que deu de errado. Não é bom mexer em senha alheia, ainda mais "por baixo do pano". O que você deve é impedir o uso de caracteres indesejados no cadastro, mas nunca MODIFICAR o valor para aceitar.